# Android onTouch and Vibration Class Combining

Tags: java, android, onclicklistener, touch-event, android-vibration

First , my English is not so good. Please use a plain language if you give answers.

I'm trying to make an app that vibrates when the user touches the screen, and stops vibrating when they remove their fingers. But the vibration class takes a value in milliseconds, and I don't know at the start how long it will need to vibrate for. How can I make it vibrate until the user's fingers are removed?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try a loop that calls vibrate for 1 ms until the user has lifted their finger.

Comment: Okey but how to use ontouch events (onDown,onUp)?

Comment: That is a completely different question, which you can easily find a solution for here on this site on via google.